# Immediate consequence in Gödels incompleteness paper

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, foundations

In the famous paper, “On Formally Undecidable Propositions of PM”, $c$ is defined as the immediate consequence of $a$ and $b$ if $a$ is the formula $\lnot b \lor c$. How does this relate to the traditional formulation  of deduction from implication involving modus ponens?

Comment: $a: b \Rightarrow c \iff \neg b \vee c$?

Answer (score 2):

> In the famous paper, On Formally Undecidable Propositions of PM, $c$ is defined as the immediate consequence of $a$ and $b$ if $a$ is the formula $\neg b \vee c$.
>
> How does this relate to the traditional formulation of deduction from implication involving modus ponens?

In other formulation: $\neg b \vee c, \; b\;\vdash\; c$

It's just a restatement of the traditional *modus ponens* rule, but substituting the equivalence: $$b\to c \quad\equiv\quad \neg b \vee c$$