# Meaning of Universal generalization in Gödel's system

Tags: logic, incompleteness

I'm reading Gödel's famous paper “On Formally Undecidable Propositions of PM” and at one point he gives the following definition:

> $c$ is defined to be the *immediate consequence* of $a$ and $b$ if $a$ is the formula  $\neg b\lor c$ or alternatively if $c$ is the formula $\forall v. a$

The first case is derived from modus ponens and it is also explained in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1151368/immediate-consequence-in-g%C3%B6dels-incompleteness-paper).

My question is:

1. What is the meaning of using "universal generalization" as a deduction rule? Is it something useful just from a formal standpoint, to make logical proofs easier, or is there a deeper reason for it?

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems to me that in conjunction with the other axiom
$$\left(\forall v.a\right) \rightarrow \mathrm{sub}\; a\left( \begin{array}{c} v \\ c\end{array}\right)$$
where $c$ is "suitably chosen", the generalization rule implies that *formulas with free variables are allowed to be true*, and in fact they have the same truth value as their generalization.

As an example of this, the formula that can be synthesized in
$$x_1=x_1$$
should be logically equivalent to
$$\forall x_1 .\: x_1=x_1$$
in Gödel's system.

So my second complementary part of the question is:

2. What would happen if we were to remove this deduction rule? Could everything work regardless without it with some adjustments? Or would it be much more complicated that it seems?  And why are formulas with free variables allowed to be true in the first place?

Formulas with free variables would still exist but will not allowed to be true, I suppose. And I assume you would need other axioms to account for things like deriving $\forall v.\: a\rightarrow c$ from $\forall v.\: a\rightarrow b$ and $\forall v.\: b\rightarrow c$ . Is that really doable in some way or not?

*Summing up*, I'm asking why universal generalization is used as a deduction rule and whether it is possible to remove it or not in Gödel's system.

Comment: Universal generalization is the only inference rule that creates formulas of the form $\forall x \phi$, where $x$ is a variable appearing in $\phi$. If no postulate is of the form $\forall x \phi$ then all formulas of the same form would be unprovable.

Comment: See [Universal generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization): "In predicate logic, universal generalization (or universal introduction) is a valid inference rule. It states that if $\vdash A(v)$ (i.e. $A(v)$  has been derived), then $\vdash \forall v \, A(v)$ (i.e  $\forall v \, A(v)$ can be derived)."

Comment: We can remove it form predicate logic (i.e. using *modus ponens* as only rule of inference) and achieve a sound and complete proof system, provided that we "enlarge" the set of predicate axioms. See H.Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&pg=PA110), page 110-112.

Comment: *Comment*: why we cannot in G's system produce the wrong proof: 1) $x=0$; 2) $\forall x \ (x=0)$ : by *Gen*; 3) $1=0$: from 2) and axiom by *MP* ? The "trick" is that we cannot have $\vdash x=0$; to prove it will be equivalent to prove $\forall x \ (x=0)$ and this is not derivable in a consistent system of arithmetic.

Comment: So, you are indeed confirming that universal generalization is more of a formal rule, while the modus ponens part is the core part of the "immediate consequence", right?

Comment: However the proposed link doesn't quite work if I'm not mistaken, since in axiom 2 (pg.112) regarding generalization, you can still substitute a formula $\forall x .a$ with some variable in place of $x$, obtaining "true" formulas with free variables (and you can also derive from them the "generalized" version using the generalization theorem at pg. 117). The universal generalization is still there but relegated to an axiom.

Comment: If you want to truly remove generalization, you need that formulas like "x=x" are not allowed to have any truth value, they can never be proved nor disproved. Such formulas become more of "n-relations", where you need to substitute the free variables with terms which aren't variables to give to them a truth value for each case. (I think they might stop to be formulas in the Gödel sense if you do that).

What can be true/false, i.e. provable/unprovable, are formulas like $\forall x. x=x$ only, where the variables cannot be free, so only their "generalized" counterpart.

Comment: Second comment (*Gen Th*, page 117): correct. "Generalization" is a sound principle of inference: if we have proved that a "generic" object $x$ is $P$, we can safely conclude that every object is $P$. The "trick" is to suitably formalize teh "generic" restriction: in Enederton's approach this is done in the said theorem with the proviso that "no previous assumptions" regarding $x$ is present in the proof.

Comment: Godel's original system is a proof system with no assumptions except mathematical axioms; if so, my example about the wrong derivation of my comemnt above amounts to saying that the error cannot happen in G's system because a formula like $x=0$ is not an axiom and cannot be derived from arithmetical sound axioms.

Comment: First comemnt: NO. In G's system - derived from [Principia Mathematica](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/principia-mathematica/) - we have many logical axioms and two (sound) inference rules: Modus Ponens and Generalization. And all works well.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not saying there is a problem using generalization, I'm wondering to what degree it is really needed, motivated by the observation that in these systems there is an excess of formulas stating the same thing ($x=x$ is the same as $\forall x. x=x$, and $x=0$ has the same truth value as $\forall x. x=0$, and so on). So dropping $x=0$ as a formula (and such) along with generalization and substitution *by variable* (which means that from $\forall x. x=x$ you can only obtain formulas like $1=1$, but not $x=x$) could still work with some adjustments.

Comment: The excess of "equivalent formulas" still holds in Enderton system, and in fact generalization is still present, not as an inference rule but translated into some axioms, so Enderton isn't really answering my question.